# Expectation of Exponential Random Variable

Tags: random-variables, exponential-distribution

I was a bit confused about this question.

> You’re clearing out your garage for a garage sale, and you want to get rid of as much stuff as possible quickly. You found a dresser and decided to sell it to the first person offering 220 or more. Assume offers to buy the dresser are independent exponential random variables with a mean of 150. The price is firm, and you keep taking offers until you receive one that is at least 220.

> Given you only accept offers at or above $220, how much money do you expect to get for your dresser?

To solve this, I first calculated the probability that any single offer is too low. I did this by just using the CDF of an exponential with mean 1/150 and P(X < 220) (not sure if this is right, or if I should do a summation). But I'm not sure how to calculate the amount of money I should expect. I'm assuming I need to find some E[X].

Comment: You are expected to find the expectation of a random variable $Y$ that satisfies: $P(Y>y)=P(X>y\mid X>220)$ where $X$ has exponential distribution with mean $150$.

Comment: Hint: $\text{Geometric(p)}$  distribution; $\pmb1_{X_1\ge 220},\pmb1_{X_2\ge 220},\pmb1_{X_3\ge 220},...$ are i.i.d. $\text{Bernoulli(p)}$ with $p=P(X_i\ge 220).$